# spiral pattern python

Tags: python

I was wondering how to print the following pattern for a given number "m" in python. My idea was to use a string to create each line separately. but I cannot deploy the output. it gives me sth different and I think I am thinking and solving a wrong way.

*Clarification: this is an extended version of a problem appeared in a local programming contest in 2019 in Nepal and not a homework or something similar. the original problem was asking to find the coordinate of final point*

Comment: What do you want this to look like for even `m`?

Comment: i mean a given input. not necessarily m. we start from (0,0) and do a spiral until we reach the input point. (the way we do spiral turn is visible in the picture I attached

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by actually simulating the snail's path.  I suspect this is easier than reverse-engineering the final pattern row by row.  Pass the N value on the command line.  This version starts from the inside and works out, which it turns out is easier.

```
import sys

N = int(sys.argv[1])

grid = [[' ']*N for _ in range(N+2)]

# Where is the center?
x = y = N // 2
if N % 4 == 3:
    x -= 1
grid[y][x] = '+'
dir = (1,0)
incr = 2

def printgrid(grid):
    for row in grid:
        print(' '.join(row))

def draw(grid,x,y,n,dir):
    for i in range(n):
        x += dir[0]
        y += dir[1]
        grid[y][x] = '-'
    grid[y][x] = '+'
    return x,y

while x+dir[0]*incr in range(N) and y+dir[1]*incr in range(N):
    x, y = draw( grid, x, y, incr, dir )
    dir = (-dir[1],dir[0])

    x, y = draw( grid, x, y, incr, dir )
    dir = (-dir[1],dir[0])
    
    incr += 2

draw( grid, x, y, incr-2, dir )
printgrid(grid)
```

Output:

```
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ python x.py 17
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
-                                
-   + - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
-   -                           -
-   -   + - - - - - - - - - +   -
-   -   -                   -   -
-   -   -   + - - - - - +   -   -
-   -   -   -           -   -   -
-   -   -   -   + - +   -   -   -
-   -   -   -       -   -   -   -
-   -   -   + - - - +   -   -   -
-   -   -               -   -   -
-   -   + - - - - - - - +   -   -
-   -                       -   -
-   + - - - - - - - - - - - +   -
-                               -
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
```

Comment: cool idea, but I think because the center of your pattern and the original one are in different directions, it is a better idea to start from the center. and btw, for other inputs which are not in form of 4k+1, the output should be different. please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I assumed, for some reason, that you had to start from the outside and figure out what the center would be.  You didn't mention that in the spec.  Starting from the center is easier, because the legs are 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4...